# What does the following block of code do, and do I need it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have really sensitive information, keep in mind. 
What does this do and why do i need it, if i even do?

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        res.header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is part of [access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), saying that whoever wants to use your web page, they can (i.e. it explicitly allows cross-origin requests).  Whether you need it or not, is on you to decide. This allows everyone to use your site's resources, which might be the whole point, or it might be a very easy target for coordinated DDoS attack. Or both.